# Returning Division in C++ Unit Test incorrectly coming back as 0

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am unit testing a C++ function using the built is Visual Studio 2015 framework. However, the test is failing and saying the actual value is 0. If I return `(y2 - y1)`, then I get a value of 99. If I return `(x2 - x1)`, I get 86400, but if I return `(y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)` I get zero. Why is this? Do I need to do something to the `Assert::AreEqual()` to tell it to deal with floats? Even if I do the division in a float and then return the variable, I still get zero?

```
float averageGradient(int x1, int x2) {
    //do some maths, the result of which: y1=-39, y2= 60, x1=683675, x2=770075
    float m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
    return (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
}
```

I am calling this with the following Unit Test:

```
TEST_METHOD(Average_Gradient) {
        int x1 = 683675;
        int x2 = x1 + 86400;
        float gradient = averageGradient(x1, x2);
        float answer = 0.001145833;
        Assert::AreEqual(answer, gradient);
    }
```

Comment: You should cast (x2 -x1) to a float value.

Comment: Division of 2 integers in C++ returns an integer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Even if I do the division in a float and then return the variable, I still get zero?

That's not what you're doing.

```
float averageGradient(int x1, int x2) {
    //do some maths, the result of which: y1=-39, y2= 60, x1=683675, x2=770075
    float m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
    return (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
}
```

First does the division on the `int`s and assigns the result (0) to a `float`. Then you do the division on `int`s again and return that.

The result of integer division just truncates it and gives an int as result as well. You gotta cast at least 1 argument to `float` before doing the division if you want to get a float as result:

```
float averageGradient(int x1, int x2) {
    //do some maths, the result of which: y1=-39, y2= 60, x1=683675, x2=770075
    float m = (y2 - y1) / (float)(x2 - x1);
    return m;
}
```

should do it.

Also where are you getting `y1` and `y2` from as you aren't taking them as arguments? Are those global variables?

Comment: The function averageGradient has a comment inside stating "do some maths, the result of which: y1=-39, y2= 60, x1=683675, x2=770075"

Comment: Thanks! One more point, when I do that, I get `0.00116043` rather than `99/86400` given the values returned when I just returned the numerator and divisor of the fraction.  This simplifies to `11/9600` and is roughly `0.001145833`?

Answer (score -2):

You should be returning the `m` variable you declared as a float rather than the calculation. Your return should say simply: `return m;`